# Automatic translation while uploading a document using Google documents list API does not work

Tags: google-docs-api

I try to automatically translate a document using version 3 of Google Document List API.
The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_and_automatically_translating_them) just says to add a "sourceLanguage" and/or a "targetLanguage" parameter to the initial HTTP POST request.

So here is the request I'm sending :

```
POST /feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?sourceLanguage=fr&targetLanguage=en
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=<authentication token>
GData-Version: 3.0
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: 163
X-Upload-Content-Type: text/plain
X-Upload-Content-Length: 50

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:docs="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007"><title>french.txt</title></entry>
```

I tried with very simple .txt files as well as .doc (french to english).
The files are uploaded correctly to the service, but translation does not occur.

The translation using Tools->Translate menu on the uploaded documents works OK, so the "translation engine" is able to perform the translation I'm trying to do through the API.

Is the documentation wrong ? How does automatic translation work ?

Comment: please show us your request or your code

Comment: I added the upload request I send to Google docs

Comment: I am running into somewhat similar problem and I'm unable to find any way by which google docs could translate my uploaded document through an API. I could only see a way to upload and download docs and simple things. no such feature as translation of Docs.